# Magento 2 : Delete products having no name using sql or admin

Tags: magento2, product, database, sql, delete

I uploaded a csv in which there were some products having no name, so it comes out blank in frontend.
I tried getting these products in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` but there were no NULL values in this table corresponding to `attribute_id` of Product Name attribute.
Is there any way to delete these products using admin/sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get all products with empty name**

```
SELECT main_tbl.* FROM catalog_product_entity main_tbl 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar name_tbl ON main_tbl.entity_id = name_tbl.entity_id AND name_tbl.attribute_id = (
        SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
)
WHERE name_tbl.value IS NULL OR name_tbl.value = ''
```

**Delete products with empty name**

```
DELETE main_tbl FROM catalog_product_entity main_tbl 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar name_tbl ON main_tbl.entity_id = name_tbl.entity_id AND name_tbl.attribute_id = (
        SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
)
WHERE name_tbl.value IS NULL OR name_tbl.value = '';
```

Comment: your delete query gives error , however select query is working fine

Comment: FIXED. Try once.

Comment: it gives error again, near LEFT JOIN keyword

Comment: It's working fine for me. In worst case make SQL statement in one line.

Comment: That's the standard JOIN should work for anyone. Try to google the error that you are having. Maybe the MySQL client or Server is too old?

Comment: Running query on cli worked for me